# How to use CI server with external configuration files with .net mvc solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, continuous-integration

Just looking for some advice on how other developers handle this type of situation.
Ok so here is the current setup

- We have an MVC 5 project
- We have external configuration files `<appSettings file="Web.secrets.config">` which are used to store 3rd party integration details.
- The configuration file is not stored in source control (we use a private github repo)
- We are in the process of setting up Appveyor for CI. For now we just want to run unit tests, but it will be used for deployment in the future.

The problem we have is that we are not allowed to store the 3rd party integration details in the source control. Some of our unit tests use these credentials.
The secrets file has to be manually copied to development machines and to the dev/live environment.
As the secrets file is not stored in source control, when it comes to run the tests on the CI server, it fails as it cannot find the file.

So my question is, how do other developers get around this problem? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are running integration tests, and not unit tests.  If you are truly unit testing, you could use hide the 3rd party integrations behind an interface then mock out the actually implementation.

You'd also want to hide the way you get configuration detail behind and interface.  Something like IProvideSecureConfiguration and mock that out as well.